# PHP MySQL Searching multiple values in one field

Tags: php, mysql, search, multiple-value

How can I store multiple values in a single SQL field **and** ensure this data is searchable?

For example I want to be able to do this

```
name | num
-----------
John | 21, 22, 34
Mike | 41, 32, 43
Dave | 12, 23, 34


$query = SELECT name from table WHERE num = '12' 
// result should be 'Dave'
```

or

```
$query = SELECT name from table WHERE num = '22' or num = 41 
// result should be John and Mike
```

I'm using PHP so I know I could serialize the data when its being input, then unserialize and search the resulting array, but the dataset is quite large so this will be quite a slow query as I will have to retrieve the entire dataset and loop through the resulting array.

Is there something I may have missed? I really don't want to have to create a table for each of the possible options as there are absolutely loads of groups and many options in each.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

**EDIT:** The above example is just an example there could be any number of 'nums'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do it that way:

Craete an entry for each combination:

```
John | 21
John | 22
John | 23
Mark | 19
Mark | 22
```

If you have any aditional informaions in youtable create 2 tables:

```
Users:
UserId |FirstName |Lastname
1      |John      |Doe
2      |Mark      |Hamill

   Options:
    UserId |Num
          1| 21
          1| 22
          1| 23
          2| 19
          2| 22
```

**If you have to stick to a existing database structure**
with just one column you can store it as a text/varchar.
just put a pipe (or any other char) at the start of your string and after each number|21|21|23|. Then you can search with LIKE '%|23|%'

This is slow and ugly as hell, but sometimes adding tables or aolums is not an option.

Comment: Would this be slower than doing it with a join? Problem for me is the sheer number of option groups and options within - which is currently stored as a PHP array and I am keen to find a suitable workaround.

Comment: A LOT SLOWER! if you have ANY other option do not do it. Just did that once because we had some 3rd party software using the database that would crash if I modifyed the db

Comment: Joins can use indexes, they aren't as evil as you are making them sound, Ashley. They are lot better solution than this would be.

Answer (score 3):

For optimal speed and efficiency, put the 'nums' in a separate table linking to the ids.

Using [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-comparison-functions.html) will work too however it also needs to do a comparison against part of the string.  Depending on the size of your data set this can also take some time.

Another option is mysql regex using [word boundaries](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp) ie:

```
SELECT name from table where nums REGEXP '[[:<:]]##[[:>:]]';
```

Each of these options will work however moving the data to a separate table is the proper method especially if there are a lot of possibilities.

For this method you would need three tables

```
People
-------
ID
NAME

Options
-------
ID
OPTION

Options_People
--------------
OPTION_ID
PEOPLE_ID
```

To get all 'people' with a specific option it's:

```
SELECT p.* FROM People p, Options_People op 
WHERE p.ID = op.PEOPLE_ID and OPTION_ID = #option#
```

To get all 'people' with any of multiple options:

```
SELECT p.* FROM People p, Options_People op 
WHERE p.ID = op.PEOPLE_ID and OPTION_ID IN ( #option1#,#option2#,#option#)
```

Answer (score 0):

A name to num pivot table is probably the most elegant way to do this

Comment: do you mean a creating a table for each group of options, with a row for each option and another table which links the two?

Comment: You should make an entry for each valid combination of 'name' and 'num'. John | 21 ; John | 22, John |23

Answer (score 0):

SELECT name,GROUP_CONCAT(num) FROM table_name GROUP BY name